# <input>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in matmul

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.9

I am having an error when inputting data that is processed in sklearn's pipeline.py
I am trying to fit a model using a quite large training data matrix X which is multiplied in sklearn's extmath.py

The problem occurs when it is tries multiple the transpose of X with X.
r = a @ b (line 189 in extmath.py)
where a=X.T and b=X

Both 'a' and 'b' are numpy arrays.

Weirdly when creating a copy of one of the arrays (X_copy = X.copy()) the error disappears. So it seems it's not an issue due to the data itself. Obviously, I have checked for NaNs and infinity values, and none were found.

The problem is repeated in different iterations of different datasets but again disappears when a copy of the array is made.

Could anyone give insight to why this may be occurring?

Comment: Other SO have deduced that `matmul` uses a special `BLAS` function when it detects `X@X.T` (where `X.T.base` is `X` itself).  That could explain why the error goes away when using a `X.T.copy()`.  I'd double check the `dtype`.

Comment: I see others have in the past encountered this due to actual bugs in OpenBLAS (for this operations specificallly). I'd make sure the versions of OpenBLAS and numpy are up to date.

Comment: It seems the problem is due to the new numpy version 1.25.0. The previous version 1.24.4 seems to work without any problems. I have created an issue in GitHub about it and hopefully, I will hear something about it.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is the link to the thread in GitHub:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24067